# Schedule a SQL INSERT from a live table to another table with a group function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I am trying to query data from 2 tables using this SQL:

```
SELECT m.site, round(avg(s.resptm),2) AS Avg_Response, 
       TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(s.starttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:')||TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(s.starttm,'MI'))/30,0)*30||':00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') endtm 
FROM s
LEFT OUTER JOIN m
ON s.KEY = m.KEY
WHERE s.starttm >= sysdate - 1
GROUP BY m.site, TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(s.starttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:')||TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(s.starttm,'MI'))/30,0)*30||':00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

This issue is that this is incredible slow because it is performing an average on 1.8 Million records.  With this in mind I want to create a new table and insert the records pre-averaged on a 10 minute basis (flexible on the time frame). The issue is that records are being inserted every few seconds and I don't want duplicate data.  Is there a good approach for this?

Comment: You are asking for a solution design without giving enough detail about the problem.  What are the tables involved how many and how fast is the data coming in.  How often do you need results (for example if you only needed an average for the prior day it would be a much different answer than if you needed it hourly.)

Comment: Yes, my apology.  I have 2 tables a and b.  One table contains a key to the other table. a.key = b.key with a 1 to many relationship.  For each key in the a table ,there can be 1 or several thousand records in the b table.  Data is coming into both tables every few seconds. I need the averaged data in the conceptual new table at the most infrequent, every 15 minutes on a 1 minute average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a lot of your time is spent doing this:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(s.starttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:')||TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(s.starttm,'MI'))/30,0)*30||':00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

*Add this as a new column to your table and only do it once when you insert the record.*

If you are running every 15 mins over millions of rows then this will save you at least 4 million calculations every 15 mins or ~ **1/4 of a million calculations a minute.**

Comment: That line is being used to put all of the columns into 30 minute groups.  If I remove it and do it later then I will need to do another average, as the first average will not have done anything but average by my site column.  Although, I see what you are saying.

Comment: no you clearly don't see what I'm saying.  What I'm saying is to do it AS you insert the original data or have a process that goes over inserted records and calculates it once.  If you have it in the query like you do then you calculate it EVERY time you run the query.  If you only calculate it once and put it in a column you will speed up your system a lot.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, that will improve the query execution time from 200 seconds down, to around 50 seconds actually.

Comment: 75% improvement -- that sounds good.  Do that.  Then use a Materialized view and you are good to go.  You can also add some indexes if you want it to run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use a materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MVIEW_SCHEMA.AVERAGED_RECORDS
NOLOGGING 
REFRESH ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT m.site, round(avg(s.resptm),2) AS Avg_Response, 
       TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(s.starttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:')||TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(s.starttm,'MI'))/30,0)*30||':00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') endtm 
FROM s
LEFT OUTER JOIN m
ON s.KEY = m.KEY
WHERE s.starttm >= sysdate - 1
GROUP BY m.site, TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(s.starttm, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:')||TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(s.starttm,'MI'))/30,0)*30||':00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Then you can refresh it whenever you want (via scheduler or cron) with:

```
exec DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('MVIEW_SCHEMA.AVERAGED_RECORDS');
```

This places all the heavy lifting on when the view refreshes, not on you selecting it.